# Disable default tooltips and leave mootools ones

Tags: mootools, tooltip

How do I disable the default tooltips on a page? I have these mootools tips working but it shows the default ones on the page also making it messy?

Comment: I left you an answer, but you must be more precise if you want precise answer. What do you mean with *"default tooltips"*? What custom tooltip script are you using? The Tips plugin from Mootools More, or another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you just need to remove the `title` attribute from the element with custom tooltips. For example:

```
// After you created the tips with something like...
var myTips = new CustomTips($$('div.myelements'));

// You remove their title attribute to remove default tips
$$('div.myelements').each(function(el) { el.setProperty('title', ''); });
```